# Notify in verbose or debug mode only

Tags: puppet

I'm looking for a way to display a `notify { ... }` message during puppet client run **only** when using

- `puppet apply <--verbose | --debug>`
- `puppet agent <--verbose | --debug>`

I'd like to display debug messages when interactively/manually running puppet on clients. 
Yet, I couldn't find a way to evaluate these *switches* in my puppet manifests. How could I achieve this for puppet 4.x?

Comment: Using different environment could be an alternative approach, but I don't want to go that way.

Comment: Have you tried setting a log_level parameter in your puppet.conf ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Puppet resources support the `loglevel` metaparameter, including `notify`. Set it to `debug` to make a resource report on that level.

```
notify { "this is a debug message": loglevel => "debug" }
```

Output from such resources is hidden by default.

The `verbose` option does not imply a specific log level.